# Создание проекта на Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Пытался создать проект на Symfony, введя в консоли:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

И получил вот это в консоли:

```
Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v4.2.1.3)
  - Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v4.2.1.3): Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download symfony/website-skeleton from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/website-skele
ton/zipball/139bac1703dc048fd0e1f4a64cc1a7aeefe93b5a" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error me
ssages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v4.2.1.3): Cloning 139bac1703


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/symfony/website-skeleton.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.

  - https://github.com/symfony/website-skeleton.git
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\user\my-project'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/symfony/website-skeleton.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in
   certificate chain

  - git@github.com:symfony/website-skeleton.git
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\user\my-project'...
    Host key verification failed.
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL
] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-inst
all] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Comment: Попросил помочь, а мне кинули минус. Нормально? Хотя бы в комментариях написали, что не так с вопросом.

Comment: [Скриншоты вместо кода и сообщений об ошибках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4692/Скриншоты-вместо-кода-и-сообщений-об-ошибках)

Comment: Дело в том, что мне никак не скопировать с PowerShell логи. О каком коде вы говорите я не понял. Что я вводил в консоли?, дак только это: composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project. Это весь код, который я могу предоставить.

Comment: [10 трюков с PowerShell](https://www.osp.ru/winitpro/2010/08/13005150/) __UPD:__ На сколько помню, в консоли можно выделить текст, и скопировать клавишами Ctrl + Insert. Если текст не выделяется, наведите курсор на верхнюю часть окна PowerShell, и вызовите контекстное меню через правую клавишу мыши, а там уже найдёте необходимый подпункт.

Comment: "Дело в том, что мне никак не скопировать с PowerShell логи." - Да ладно.

Comment: @SonicMyst или ещё вариант: выделить необходимый текст, и кликнуть правую клавишу мыши - выделение будет сброшено, а текст сохранится в буфер обмена, и вы сможете его вставить здесь обычным Ctrl + V.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь в PowerShell.

Comment: А как вы PHP интерпретатор ставили?

Comment: Ввел php -v и вот результат: PHP 7.2.11 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2018 02:39:52) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x86 )

Comment: У меня была аналогичная проблема но с Laravel https://laravel.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=365 вот по этой теме решал... А второй раз скачал с офф сайта PHP архив распаковал указал пути и проблем вообще не было